# How to stop Service when app is paused or destroyed but not when it switches to a new Activity?

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, onpause, android-intentservice

Currently I have a `Service` which I am using to play a sound file in the background whilst the app is open:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.setVolume(100, 100);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }
}
```

And the `Service` is started in my `MainActivity` like so:

```
BackgroundSoundService backgroundSoundService = new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
```

I want the `Service` to continue to run whilst the app is open, although to stop when the app is minimised or destroyed. I thought the initial solution to this would be to override `onPause` and `onDestroy`, and implement this line:

```
stopService(backgroundSoundService);
```

However when I then switch to another `Activity`, `onPause` is then triggered and the `Service` stops. How can I ensure that the `Service` continues to run as long as the application is open in the foreground but stops when the app is minimised or closed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `onBackPressed` in order to discover when your android app is going to be minimized.

You probably have an Activity Which is the main `MainActivity` that on **back pressed** will cause the App to minimize. Just stop the `Service` then.

Btw you should use a **Singleton** in order to keep a Reference for your `backgroundSoundService`

Make all your Activities that can minimize the app Extends this `BaseActivity`

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //check if should be minimized...
        //if so stop the Service
    }

}
```

> Need a solution for Home button

This is tricky because there is no Key event in order to distinguish `Home pressed.

What you can do is to use [isFinishing](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) method in `onPause`.

When activity will go to the `Background` it will **NOT** finish when pressing the **Home Page** key

So just have a boolean to check if you called (Using `Intent`) other Activity.

the update your `onPause` method to:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if(!isFinishing()){
        if(!calledOtherActivity){
            stopService(serviceRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea. However it doesn't cover for me pressing the `Home` button and I'd also have to override `onBackPressed` in every Activity to get the desired result.

Comment: You should override `onBackPressed` only the Activity that can minmize the app. If you have several such activities then i've updated my Answer for this scenario..