# Cannot understand: 'calledOtherActivity'

Tags: android, service

I've recently found a code that could solve my background service problem, but I don't understand one part of it. Could you tell me what should I write in *!calledOtherActivity*? This part is red in my code and the hint says: " cannot resolve symbol 'calledOtherActivity' "

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if(!isFinishing()){
        if(!calledOtherActivity){
            stopService(serviceRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its a boolian value create a one an initialize it! to `stopService(serviceRef);` get called that if condition needs to be `true` --> ! -this is NOT operator , so `!calledOtherActivity = true`

Comment: Could you write how to do it? I would be thankful

Comment: `private  boolean calledOtherActivity;` you can assign `true` and `false` to a  `boolean` by default its   `false` to go inside to your if `calledOtherActivity` needs to be `false` then its like this -> if(NOT FALSE) = if (true)

Comment: did you get that?

Comment: I didn't really. 
The last lines of this question's answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252733/how-to-stop-service-when-app-is-paused-or-destroyed-but-not-when-it-switches-to

Answer (score 1):

let's understand the Situation

```
if( condition )
{
// if condition is true it goes here
}
else
{
// bah condition is false meaning !true
}
```

If the *condition* in the above statement is *false*, then the statements in the *else block* will always be executed.
If  it is *true* it goes inside it like i  commented

This condition only can be *true* or *false*

and since you have only one in the condition called `calledOtherActivity` it needs to carry true or false so its a boolean

```
private boolean calledOtherActivity;
```

by default its value is *false*

looking to your condition it is  `if(!calledOtherActivity)` as i said to go inside this it needs to be true
`!` <--- this is NOT operator this *inverts the value of a boolean*

so if you pass calledOtherActivity with a *false* value  because of this NOT operator the full output of the condition becomes *true*

Comment: Fine, but how to check if you called (Using Intent) other Activity?

Comment: @Old York  i did not get what you said can you elaborate

Comment: @Old York from that answer what i get was when you call the other activity you can change the boolean value, you can assign true or false to it depending on your requirement

Comment: My purpose is to make my service playing music stop when I turn off the screen or close the app, not while switching activities. Maybe you can help me with this @Charuka?

Comment: @Old York what i can suggest is if you want to follow this concept  .. have a look at the activity life cycle -as screen turns off your activity becomes invisible which triggers `onPause` followed by `onStop`

Screen on, on the other hand, triggers `onStart` followed by `onResume` so use those methods and pause/stop your service and continue/start and when you close app onDistroy gets called